# SCSS import hierarchy

Tags: css, sass

I want to structure my project CSS in a hierarchy like so:

```
app {
    interface1 {
        gadget1 {}
    }
}
```

And I want to split this into numerous smaller CSS files:

```
app.scss
_interface1.scss
_gadget1.scss
```

Can I import like this:

```
/* app.scss */
app {
    @import 'interface1'
    @import 'interface2'
}

/* _interface1.scss */
interface 1 {
    @import 'gadget1'
}

/* _gadget1.scss */
gadget1 {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    /* ...etc... */
}
```

Or what is the best way to achieve this end structure?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: Yes it is possible to do exactly that.

Downloaded SASS and tried it.